# Move a file in to multiple files but only if it does not already exist in certain a folder location

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch file to run each day that copies multiple copies of a file to a location then moves the original file to an archive. The full original filename varies each day with non-sequential numbers in the middle so a mask is used with (*) wildcard. The original file is then archived in an archive location.

```
copy "\\source-location\source_file*.txt "\\new-location\source_file1.txt" >> c:\logs\log.txt 2>&1
copy "\\source-location\source_file*.txt "\\new-location\source_file2.txt" >> c:\logs\log.txt 2>&1
copy "\\source-location\source_file*.txt "\\new-location\source_file3.txt" >> c:\logs\log.txt 2>&1
move "c:\source location\source_file*.txt "\\new-location\archive\" >> c:\logs\log.txt 2>&1
```

The problem I have is I do not have control over the source location. The previous day's files should be removed form the source location by the administrators of that location but sometimes this is not done. As I am using a (*) wildcard, this means sometimes two files get merged together when the copy commands are executed resulting in duplicated data from the previous day being appended.

I need the script to first check if any files in the source-location already exist in the new-location\archive directory. If so, ignore them and copy any remaining files only.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: well, I would have just used `robocopy`. Run `robocopy /?` from `cmd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All source file patterns miss `"` after `.txt`. So the posted code with this correction would be:

```
copy "\\source-location\source_file*.txt" "\\new-location\source_file1.txt" >> c:\logs\log.txt 2>&1
copy "\\source-location\source_file*.txt" "\\new-location\source_file2.txt" >> c:\logs\log.txt 2>&1
copy "\\source-location\source_file*.txt" "\\new-location\source_file3.txt" >> c:\logs\log.txt 2>&1
move "\\source location\source_file*.txt" "\\new-location\archive\" >> c:\logs\log.txt 2>&1
```

But one solution would be using a **FOR** loop with an **IF** condition:

```
(for %%I in ("\\source-location\source_file*.txt") do if not exist "\\new-location\archive\%%~nxI" (
    copy "%%I" "\\new-location\source_file1.txt"
    copy "%%I" "\\new-location\source_file2.txt"
    copy "%%I" "\\new-location\source_file3.txt"
    move "%%I" "\\new-location\archive\"
)) >>c:\logs\log.txt 2>&1
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`